# symfony number internationalization

Tags: php, symfony

I have a problem when I try to save data from inputs that has a mask. For example, the input has the value **1.234,66** but when I post the form the value is **1234**.

The value **locale** in my config.yml is **es_PY** and the form configuration it's as following:

```
->add('impuesto', 'number', array(
'attr' => array('class' => 'impuesto',
    'readonly' => 'readonly',
    'style' => 'width: 5em;'),
'grouping' => true,
'precision' => $precision ))
```

I use Symfony 2.6.9 and for the view I use the jquery.inputmask.

Whats can be wrong?

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write a [DataTransformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) using the [NumberFormatter](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) class

But personally, I'd rather leave this work to the front-end https://www.slightfuture.com/webdev/html5-input-number-localization

Answer (score 0):

I checked the php.ini and the extension intl was not active, now I try with this extension and it works! thanks for the reply and the advice.